# Copy Values only from cells in one column to cells in another column on the same sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have three columns. Based on the value in column A, a formula in Column B generates a string. How can I store the value only and not formula of the cells in Column B to cells in Column C. Data in Column A keeps adding up so probably a function or script would help.

I started something like this:

```html
function moveValuesLeft(sour) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange(sour)
  var aValues = source.getValues();
  

}
```

Now I dont know how to save it at the destination cell as a value only.

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SmtJJEcznmQ2XQeYk6jFxNJ3l2vxVyuj7CTmvYmGrRY/edit?usp=sharing)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can we see a readonly copy of your spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi Here is the link for the sheet.

Comment: Hi Here is the link for the sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SmtJJEcznmQ2XQeYk6jFxNJ3l2vxVyuj7CTmvYmGrRY/edit?usp=sharing What we need to implement is that on selecting a value from Column A in Payments sheet, it currently fetches a value (Bank Name) from Freelancers sheet and stores in column C in Payments sheet. We need to move the value only from cell in Column C to corresponding cell in Column B. So that any change in the Bank Name in Freelancers sheet does not change the existing values in Column B.